# Python pandas - Possible issue with multi indexing column names of different types

Tags: python, pandas, multi-index

The following code leads to the exception: `KeyError: u'the label [37,5 cl ] is not in the [columns]'`.

```
df = pd.read_csv('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/AntoineGautier/Data/master/new.txt')
df.rename({'1': 1, '3': 3, '0':0}, axis=1, inplace=True)
df.set_index(list(df.columns[:3]), inplace=True)
df.sort_index(inplace=True)
for idx in df.index:
    tmp = df.loc[idx]
```

No exception if all column names are strings.

Comment: which pandas version are you using? you can find out with `pd.__version__`

Comment: pandas version 0.22.0

Answer (score -1):

If you are iterating over an multiindex, `idx` is a tuple, therefore you should use `df.loc[list(idx)]`, this gives the expected result:

```
In [22]: df.loc[list(idx)]
Out[22]:
                                            5_x    5_y _merge  id_stock
1    3        0
1949 37,5 cl  Château LAFITE ROTHSCHILD   759.0  798.0   both        35
              Château LAFITE ROTHSCHILD   798.0  759.0   both        36
```

**EDIT**: You can also do the same with `df.loc[slice(idx)]`, compare [Multiindexing in the docs](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/advanced.html#using-slicers).

**EDIT2**: Compare the following ones:

```
In [38]: tuple(idx)
Out[38]: (1949, '37,5 cl ', 'Ch\xc3\xa2teau LAFITE ROTHSCHILD ')

In [39]: (idx)
Out[39]: (1949, '37,5 cl ', 'Ch\xc3\xa2teau LAFITE ROTHSCHILD ')

In [40]: list(idx)
Out[40]: [1949, '37,5 cl ', 'Ch\xc3\xa2teau LAFITE ROTHSCHILD ']

In [41]: [idx]
Out[41]: [(1949, '37,5 cl ', 'Ch\xc3\xa2teau LAFITE ROTHSCHILD ')]
```

The two first ones don't work while the last two does.

Comment: Selecting with tuple should work according to http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/advanced.html#using-slicers. Strangely the list conversion indeed solves the issue though...

Comment: Oh yes, but there you somehow almost always have slices.. I'll read that and extend my answer if I find something better.

Comment: Locating with a list is actually incorrect on a multi-indexed dataframe. The list is interpreted as a set of values for the first key only. Cf. :
 `df = pd.DataFrame({'a': [0,1,2], 'b': [2,4,5], 'val': ['x', 'y', 'z']})` and `df.set_index(['a', 'b'], inplace=True)`. `df.loc[[0, 2]]` returns the 2 lines corresponding to values `0` and `2` of key `a` whereas `df.loc[(0, 2)]` returns the expected first line (though proper syntax is rather `df.loc[(0, 2), :]`).

Comment: That's not fully correct. Locating with a list to get the only elements with that index works if not all of them are integers, if some are strings. Otherwise it's like you stated. Try `df.loc[[0,'2']]` in your example, that works fine. Whatever, I'd suggest to use the `df.loc[slice(idx)]` or `df.loc[[idx]]`, they both give the expected result.

Comment: `df.loc[slice(idx)]` does not throw any exception but does not return the lines corresponding to `idx`, rather the lines from first index to `idx` (with is consistent with the meaning of `slice`). `df.loc[[idx]]` is OK. `df.loc[idx, :]` should be OK in any case and considered as the prefered syntax. So a bug report has been filed here: https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/19517

Comment: @Albers: Thanks for the revenge down-vote run (on 4 of my answers in less than one minute after your last comment), a true mark of a gentleman really... As for your answer, it has been downvoted because it contains some misleading indications that have been commented on.